# Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working with an existing oracle database that contains a lot of lines which I connected to my spring boot app. When I want to add an entity `Student` in post request I got this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated (c##admin.STUDENT_PK)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.generateBatchUpdateException(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10346)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatchWithoutQueue(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10108)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9988)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9940)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:262)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:127)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:121)
        ... 147 common frames omitted
```

In the database `c##admin.STUDENT_PK` is related to `ID` field of student table I have another entity Professor and I dont have this problem with it.
I can't change this constraint in the database.

here is the entity Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //attributes, getters, setters
}
```

Also I am using liquibase in this project. Please any help how to solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried saving a single Student ?